# RedDot OpenText query to find out which user change a file?

Tags: opentext, reddot, cordys-opentext

I am learning RedDot OpenText CMS and wondering if there is a database query that I can run against the project data to select each file and find out who change which file recently? There should be a way to see the history of each file and the dates it changed by who?

The database schema was at one point posted here: http://reddotcmsblog.com/project-database-schema (now available on the way back machine) - this seems possible.

Thank you